# Access field log table with doctrine through annotations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I am working on an existing project, so changing the tables may not be an option since the database is accessed through a legacy system and my new system with Symfony 3.3+ and Doctrine 2.5

The old system logged changes to some fields in the following table structure:

Table: log_tableAttribute
Fields:

id

deleted

table_name

attribute_name

table_primary_key_value

old_value

new_value

user_id

comment

I need to access these values for example in
Table: product
Fields:

id

name

Since the log table is used for different tables and fields, my idea was to access these log entries through a OneToMany relation on the Product side like this:
I cannot enter a name for the Join Colum but have to use static values: 0, product, name - and I do not know if that is possible and how this is configured

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LogTableAttribute")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="%defaultValue: 0%??", referencedColumnName="deleted"),
 *    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="%defaultValue: product%??", referencedColumnName="table_name"),
 *    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="%defaultValue: name%??", referencedColumnName="attribute_name"),
 *    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="table_primary_key_value")
 * })
 */
private $nameLog;
```

Is there any chance getting these log entries directly from the Product entity  without using a Repository class on "LogTableAttribute" and getting log entries throug a service that I make available within the templates as well?

Comment: not sure whether I understand your question. if the relation is correctly defined a simple getter on $nameLog will provide you with a DoctrineCollection of LogTableAttribute objects. or what do I miss?

Comment: "if the relation is correctly defined" this is the missing part for me. When you look at the code block, I cannot enter a name for the Join Colum but have to use static values: 0, product, name - and I do not know if that is possible and how this is configured. I edited the questions to make that part clear.

Comment: You could try to work with [JoinColumn*s*](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumns) - but to be honest that will get tricky - why not using regular Repositories?

Comment: JoinColumns was my approach that I was trying to solve with this questions. As you can see in my last sentence below the code block. Using a repository would force me to create a service or put an array of log data for each product into the template that I will access in a foreach block. This may seems to be easier for getting the data but not for working with it in a template

Comment: I saw your statement but I am asking why you wouldn't use repositories - it'll be much easier and I am not aware of any way how to achieve your goal via standard annotations. but maybe someone knows better.

Comment: Thanks for replying on my question @LBA, for now I am using a service and access the data via repository class